# Change Plone default URL

Tags: url, virtualhost, plone

I'm using Plone 3.3.5, installed using the unified installer and run ning standalone without Apache.

By default, you can access plone in http://localhost:8080/Plone and I'd rather change the /Plone part with /Docs.

I've tried tweaking the virtual host monster, but couldn't find a way to change the url.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Go to the zope management interface.

Mark the Plone folder with the check mark and click the rename button.

Rename Plone to Docs and confirm.

go to http://localhost:8080/Docs and you should see your plone instance

Comment: Note that renaming a Plone site object isn't very well supported and can break internal structures. It is certainly not recommendable on larger sites with a lot of history!

Comment: What Martijn says is true. If you're starting out, another route could be to add a new Plone object with the name you want in the ZMI, and delete the original ("Plone") object. If you want to keep the content you have in the old object, you could copy (not cut) and paste the relevant content items/folders into the new object before deleting the old one. (You want to *copy* in order to make sure the new object isn't referencing child objects of the old one.)